# User Update Page In Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Im trying to implement an user update page in my Meteor app. My `router.js`:

```
Router.route('/company/:_id/update/', {
  name: 'CompanyUpdate',
  data: function() { return Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id);}
});
```

The URL I use is (ignore the polymer tags):

```
<paper-icon-button icon="perm-identity" onclick="location.href='{{pathFor 'CompanyUpdate' _id=userId}}'"></paper-icon-button>
```

When that URL is clicked, I get: `http://localhost:3000/company/null/update`. It takes me to the page but I cant get no information from the user's database. Not sure why I get a "null" in the url.

I am still learning meteor and would like someone to explain what is missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userId` in your template in null. Try using the default `{{currentUser}}` template which calls `Meteor.user()`. So something like this should work:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="perm-identity" onclick="location.href='{{pathFor 'CompanyUpdate' _id=currentUser._id}}'"></paper-icon-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got help from the #meteor community. The answers came from use users: "pchoo" and "rpitt". Many thanks for the answer:

```
{{with currentUser}}
  <paper-icon-button icon="perm-identity" onclick="location.href='{{pathFor 'CompanyUpdate' _id=id}}'"></paper-icon-button>
{{/with}}
```

The above solved my issue.